# The target is narrow/ limited / tight?

Tags: adjectives

If I would like to describe a target of a very small group of people, like age 14 to 16 , girls, should I say the target is narrow / limited / tight or any other adjectives?

Which one sounds better?

Comment: This very much depends on context. If it is a time window, then 'tight' would seem particularly appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word target comes from a word meaning a shield - the set up being that archers used to use the shields to practice their aim.

So I think your best choice of word should retain something of a shield. I think limited and tight might not work that well. Narrow seems ok. Small maybe?

Answer (score 1):

If you are describing a narrow range of people by age, you might want to try age group.

Example:

- Our target group is girls, between the ages of 14 to 16.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for "restricted target".